# How to replace init(destination:tag:selection:label:) with NavigationLink(value:label:) in Swift for iOS16?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using the following Swift code to do 2 things in my iPhone app:

1. Call method `somethingElse()` when button is clicked
2. Change view to `SecondView()`

**Code**

```
struct PrimaryView: View {
  @State var buttonSelected: Int? = nil
  
  func onSubmit() {
    somethingElse()
    self.buttonSelected = 1
  }

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), tag: 1, selection: $buttonSelected) {
        Button(action: {
          onSubmit()
        }) {
          Text("Click me")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine but I get the following warning:

> 'init(destination:tag:selection:label:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0:
> use NavigationLink(value:label:) inside a List within a
> NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView...

**Question:** How do I refactor this code so the warning goes away but the functionality stays the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you follow the advice on the warning, you'd get something like this:

```
NavigationStack {
    List {
        NavigationLink(value: 1) { // use some tag here
            Button(action: {
                onSubmit()
            }) {
                Text("Click me")
            }
        }
    }.navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { _ in 
        // check the closure parameter here to return a different view
        SecondView() 
    }
}
```

Of course, this will give you a `List` instead. If you don't want that, the other overload, [`navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationdestination(ispresented:destination:)?changes=_8), seems to work. The code is simply

```
NavigationStack {
    Button(action: {
        onSubmit()
    }) {
        Text("Click me")
    }.navigationDestination(isPresented: $buttonSelected, destination: { SecondView() })
}
```

With `buttonSelected` changed to a `Bool`:

```
@State var buttonSelected: Bool = false

func somethingElse() {
    print("something Else")
}

func onSubmit() {
    somethingElse()
    self.buttonSelected = true
}
```

Comment: Note with the first option, you don't have to put `NavigationLink` in a `List`. However the behavior is clunky, since clicking on the button doesn't actually send you to the view, instead you need to click somewhere outside the button, but still inside the `NavigationLink`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yeah, the suggestion in the warning is rather unhelpful :-(

Comment: Oh, wow this is a great answer, thanks! I really dig the solution using `.navigationDestination(isPresented: $buttonSelected, destination: { SecondView() })` 